# React - Map & useRef - Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This may already have an answer but I have not been able to find one that doesn't suggest a work around that doesn't make use of `ref`. That said, using `ref` may not be the preferred approach.

I have a table where each row has a popover menu as the last column. Currently, the `ref` will always point to the last mapped item (last row's menu).

How can I make sure each row's menu has its own reference?

```
const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);
const menu = useRef(null);

return (
    <table>
        <caption>Table</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col 1</th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
                <th>Col 3</th>
                <th>Col 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {data.map((item, index) => 
            <tr key={ index }>
                <td>{ item.a }</td>
                <td>{ item.b}</td>
                <td>{ item.c }</td>
                <td>
                    <div className="popover-group">
                        <button 
                            className="popover-menu-button" 
                            onClick={ () => setShowMenu(!showMenu) }
                        >Show Menu</button>
                        <div className="popover-menu" ref={ menu }>
                            /* menu content */
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        )}
        </tbody>
    </table>
)
```

I should add that I will need to be able to access the specific menu elsewhere like here

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (showMenu){
        menu.current.style.setProperty('opacity', '1')
        menu.current.style.setProperty('display', 'block')
    } else {
        menu.current.style.setProperty('opacity', '0')
        menu.current.style.setProperty('display', 'none')
    }
}, [showMenu])
```

So I will need to access `menu.current[/*some index*/]`. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Make your `useRef` an array and assign each of the menu items to a different index in the array. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sguhqi

Comment: Does only one menu show at a time?

Comment: You should be able to achieve this using state and not require refs. This example uses a state value to track which menu item index is currently shown and applies an extra class to show a popup menu, this is extremely basic example but it should show the rough logic needed if you don't want to use refs. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n8jvpe?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Thanks for the help @JacobSmit that seems to work fine for me. I do have one other question. I have a `useEffect` for whenever `openMenu` changes that should check if the use clicked anywhere that is not the menu. This closes the menu if clicking anywhere else. How can I accomplish this with your solution? Something like `if (openMenu && /*e.target not this menu*/) { setOpenMenu(null) }`

Comment: I usually use my own version of a click outside handler similar to https://github.com/airbnb/react-outside-click-handler/blob/master/src/OutsideClickHandler.jsx or the Material UI one if the app uses that. This allows you to wrap any component with the OutsideClickHandler and run an event when a click is registered outside of the component or any of it's children. This would allow you to set the selected index back to null on outside click.